# Graph API create a driveItem with package property set

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Using Microsoft graph API there are ways to create folders (as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-post-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)) or files (described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)) `driveItems`.
However the `driveItem` also allows to have a `package` property, which makes it something different (currently only a package of `{'type': 'oneNote'}` can exist); it can easily be read but I can’t find a way to create such a package.

Using the OneNote graph API is not an option, since we work with tenant ID and it does not allow to create OneNote notebooks.
Am I missing something or is it really impossible (getting familiar with graph API I suspect the second)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to set a `package` property because it is read-only.

Resources:

[driveItem properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)